# Enumset error in hadoop sequence file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, sequencefile

I am trying to create sequence file with metadata and createflag, but it gives me the error:

> cannot resolve method for createwriter

I am new to Hadoop and Java programming. I have added the code below.

I am trying to add multiple images in a sequence file with keys. Once the sequence file is created if it not exist and if it exist then append image data.

```
Path path = new Path("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/image_data/SequenceFileCodecTest.seq");
FSDataInputStream in = null;
Text key = new Text();
BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
SequenceFile.Metadata metadata = null;
SequenceFile.Writer writer = null;
Option optPath = SequenceFile.Writer.file(path);
Option optKey = SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(key.getClass());
Option optVal = SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(value.getClass());
Option optCom = SequenceFile.Writer.compression(SequenceFile.CompressionType.RECORD);
final EnumSet<CreateFlag> flag = EnumSet.of(CreateFlag.CREATE,CreateFlag.APPEND);
writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf,optPath,optKey, optVal,optCom,new DefaultCodec(),metadata,flag);
```